# What are the open source and free tools to automatically scan Java application for security vulnerabilities?

Tags: java, javascript, security, grails

These tools are also knows as security scanners. I am looking for such open source and free scanners for Ajax driven grails/Java web application that would identify major security flaws such as Injection and XSS Attacks. Such top 10 security risks are identified by OWASP Top 10.

As a bonus question what is Java/groovy source code level scanner for such purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to use [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). Sonar has the ability to analyse the quality of your code and in addition to detect :

- SQL Injection Vulnerability
- Password Management Vulnerability
- Error Handling and Logging flaws
- Insecure direct object reference
- Servlet reflected cross site scripting vulnerability

etc...

You can read [this](http://www.sonarsource.org/sonar-to-identify-security-vulnerabilities/) for more information !

Some great screencasts are available [here](http://www.sonarsource.org/screencasts/).

A online demo Sonar is available [here](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/) if you want to test the tool before installing.